# Filtering on 1 to many relation not working in SQL Cube

Tags: sql-server, olap-cube

I'm very new to SQL Cubes so please be gentle here.

I have a main table with a list of defects in it and then that table has a pile of foreign key links to other tables to list more detail. DefectTable.FactoryId -> Factory.Name for example.

Now in my cube when I check a list of defects I can filter by Factory Name quite easily and everything works fine.

I now however have a table called DefectResult which can contain multiple records for each defect row in DefectTable.

However now when I drop a DefectResult in the cube and try filter by Factory Name it doesn't filter them and rather just replicates all the results for each factory.

So it looks something like this

Factor <- DefectTable <- DefectResult

With the DefectTable being the main starting point..

The question is simply, why isn't it filtering by factory and how do I get it to do that?